# Determine whether 2 elements represent the same left H-coset

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just learnt the properties of cosets this week and still very confused. Could anyone help me?

My homework question is:
[Determine whether 2 elements represent the same left H-coset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuSz7.jpg)

On my text book I have the following properties:
1) $aH=bH$ iff $a \in bH$
2) $aH=bH$ iff $a^{-1}b \in H$

so for example, in order to check if $a^3$ and a represent the same left $H$ coset, I firstly check whether $a^{-1}a=a^{-2}$ in $a^2$? Also, what does $a^{-2}$ in $a^2$ actually mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is the second condition that is used.

For your example, if you want to know if $a^{3}H$ is the same coset as $aH$ you need to work out $a^{-3}a$ and check to see if it belongs to $H$. If it does the cosets will be the same and if it does not then the cosets will be different. Now $a^{-3}a$ is $a^{(-3+1)}=a^{2}$. So you need to check if $a^{2}\in H$.

Comment: Yes. My question is how to check if a[exp]-2 ∈H? or in this case, how to check whether or not a[exp]-2 ∈<a[exp]2>?

Comment: You need to be given what the subgroup $H$ is. I do not know where you are getting the $a^{-2}$ in $a^{2}$ from in your question. Elements belong to sets. Are you asking how to prove these conditions?